Regression on SQL query texts. Good ML model architecture
Fast regression on SQL queries. Good ML model architecture.
Our goal is to predict which SQL engine (there are 2 currently) will be faster to execute a given query.
The input is the query text and in the future we might be able to get some information about the table sizes.
The model needs to run fast (milliseconds).
What would be the best model architecture for this task?
Some thoughts and sub-questions:
The input queries are not very long, but have variable lengths. A fixed-input model will likely not work.
The model output is a couple of numbers (one for each engine), not a sequence.
Transformers vs RNN (or maybe even CNN). What kind of architecture would be best here given the relatively small size of inputs?
Probably best to train a model from scratch. Most existing LLMs are too big and slow for such specialized task. The SQL language is a special small vocabulary.
Would it be best to run a model for each sub-query, calculate the "thought vector", then insert that thought vector when processing the parent query? Or are models text processing architectures smart enough to not benefit from such manual feature crafting?
What would be the best way to feed numerical data (e.g. table sizes) to the model alongside the query text? Token-based parsing is not great at numbers, so this likely needs to be a side-channel (e.g. extra numbers of the side of an embedding). Can transformers handle numerical data? It seems to me that given the cross-attention mechanism, numerical data will be pretty mangled in the process.
Would massaging the queries (e.g. moving the "SELECT" clause to the end of the query) help the model better understand the queries?

two years ago it would be a different answer, but today you have to run LLM API to get the embeddings. I would feed the sql schema with table sizes as a context, of course

Are you sure? The LLM APIs seem too slow (not quite 1ms latency) and have troubles even with basic number understanding (e.g. "Is 3.9 bigger than 3.11?"). Re: Embeddings: Are you proposing to use common LLMs to calculate embedding and then train a couple of dense layers to create the regression output?

1ms latency is not available over internet APIs

This is why I'm asking about a model training and architecture rather than which API to use. There are also local LLMs, but I'm not sure they're fast enough for my use case. And I'm not sure they'll be able to do the regression I need either.

what's the purpose of this application?

As mentioned in the question: Choose the best (fastest) SQL execution engine for the given job (query) issued by the user. For this to make sense, the selection model needs to be significantly faster than the query execution time.
